# Problema al escanear un caracter y guardarlo en una estructura

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Al escanear el sexo y guardarlo en la estructura las funciones `CancionMasVotada` y `Premio` me imprimen resultados erroneos, en cambio si quito el scanf del sexo todo funciona a la perfección.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct canciones {
    int codigo;
    char genero;
    int puntos;
    char nombre[100];
};
typedef struct canciones CANCIONES;
struct oyente {
    int cedula;
    int edad;
    char sexo;
    int eleg[3];
    int puntos;
};
typedef struct oyente OYENTE;
int i, j, k = 0, aux = 0, x;
OYENTE oyentes[3];
CANCIONES canciones[10];
void Menu();
void TomarDatosOyente();
void CancionMasVotada();
void PtsOyente();
void Premio();
int main () {
    Menu();
    TomarDatosOyente();
    CancionMasVotada();
    PtsOyente();
    Premio();
    return 0;
}
void Menu(){
  printf("\n\tEMISORA DE RADIO\n\n");
  printf("Digite el listado de canciones:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Cancion #%d: ", i+1);
    gets(canciones[i].nombre);
    printf(" Genero <P-pop / R-rap / K-rock / T-Romantica> : ");
    scanf("%s", &canciones[i].genero);
  }
}
void TomarDatosOyente(){
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf(" Oyente #%d \n", i+1);
    printf(" Cedula: ");
    scanf("%d", &oyentes[i].cedula);
    printf(" Edad: ");
    scanf("%d", &oyentes[i].edad);
    printf(" sexo: "); 
    scanf("%s", &oyentes[i].sexo); // aqui esta el problema
    printf(" Digite los datos de sus canciones favoritas\n");
    aux = 3;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf(" Cancion #%d\n", j+1);
      printf(" Codigo <1-10> : ");
      scanf("%d", &oyentes[i].eleg[j]);
      k = oyentes[i].eleg[j];
      canciones[k-1].codigo = k;
      canciones[k-1].puntos += aux;
      aux--;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
  }
}
void CancionMasVotada(){
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      if (canciones[j].puntos < canciones[j+1].puntos) {
        aux = canciones[j].puntos;
        canciones[j].puntos = canciones[j+1].puntos;
        canciones[j+1].puntos = aux;

        k = canciones[j].codigo;
        canciones[j].codigo = canciones[j+1].codigo;
        canciones[j+1].codigo = k;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("--------------------------------\n--------------------------------\n");
printf("La cancion mas votada es %s con %d votos\n",      canciones[canciones[0].codigo - 1].nombre, canciones[0].puntos);
printf("La segunda cancion mas votada es %s con %d votos\n", canciones[canciones[1].codigo - 1].nombre, canciones[1].puntos);
  printf("--------------------------------\n--------------------------------\n");
}
void PtsOyente(){
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  aux = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  if (oyentes[i].eleg[j] == canciones[0].codigo) {
      oyentes[i].puntos += 30;
      aux++;
  }else if (oyentes[i].eleg[j] == canciones[1].codigo) {
      oyentes[i].puntos += 20;
    if (aux == 1) {
        oyentes[i].puntos += 10;
    }
  }
}
  }
}
void Premio(){
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (oyentes[j].puntos < oyentes[j+1].puntos) {
        aux = oyentes[j].puntos;
        oyentes[j].puntos = oyentes[j+1].puntos;
        oyentes[j+1].puntos = aux;

        k = oyentes[j].cedula;
        oyentes[j].cedula = oyentes[j+1].cedula;
        oyentes[j+1].cedula = k;
      }
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Oyente de cedula: %d\nPuntos: %d\n", oyentes[i].cedula, oyentes[i].puntos);
  }
      printf("El oyente de cedula %d ha ganado el premio con un total de %d puntos\n", oyentes[0].cedula, oyentes[0].puntos);
}
```

[image]

elgiendo primero las canciones 1,2 y 3 luego la 4,1 y 6 y por ultimo 7,8 y 2 debe dar este resultado
[image]

Al escanear el sexo y elegir las mismas canciones me imprime estos datos incorrectos, ya efectue el cambio de `%s` a `%c` como me habian dicho más abajo

Gracias

Comment: Estás scaneando un solo  carácter, utiliza %c, %s es para una cadena de carácteres:     scanf("%c", &oyentes[i].sexo);

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando pidas ayuda con un error, debes mostrar el error, asi como el resultado que decis que es el correcto.

Comment: post editado, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Estás scaneando un solo carácter, utiliza `%c`, `%s` es para una cadena de carácteres:

```
scanf("%c", &oyentes[i].sexo);
```

Como dice [acá](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Input-Conversions.html)

> La conversión '%c' es la más simple: coincide con un número fijo de
>   caracteres, siempre. El ancho máximo del campo indica cuántos
>   caracteres leer; si no especifica el máximo, el valor predeterminado
>   es 1. Esta conversión no agrega un carácter nulo al final del texto
>   que lee. Tampoco omite los caracteres iniciales en blanco. Lee con
>   precisión los siguientes n caracteres, y falla si no puede obtenerlos.

Comment: usando %c no se resuelve el problema

Answer (score 0):

**Las variables no deben ser globales**

Salvo excepciones muy contadas, y ninguna es aplicable a tu caso, las variables no deben ser globales y la explicación es muy simple:

- Las variables globales pueden ser utilizadas, sin control alguno, desde cualquier parte del código. No puedes asumir que una variable global va a tener un valor determinado y, seguramente, tengas que tratar la variable en todo momento como si no estuviese inicializada.
- En entornos multi-hilo el problema se recrudece.
- No tienen ámbito (es decir, su ámbito es toda la aplicación) y es facil que la variable acabe solapada con una variable local... lo que complica la lectura y comprensión del código.

Es preferible tener esto:

```
void func()
{
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    // ...
}
```

A esto:

```
int i;

void func()
{
  for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
    // ...
}
```

**Ojo con los rangos**

Función con el premio del día:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    if (oyentes[j].puntos < oyentes[j+1].puntos) {
      aux = oyentes[j].puntos;
      oyentes[j].puntos = oyentes[j+1].puntos;
      oyentes[j+1].puntos = aux;

      k = oyentes[j].cedula;
      oyentes[j].cedula = oyentes[j+1].cedula;
      oyentes[j+1].cedula = k;
    }
  }
}
```

Lo primero que chirría de esta función es que usas dos bucles (`i` y `j`) y sin embargo luego únicamente usas uno de los dos índices (`j`). Después miras con más detenimiento y te encuentras esto `oyentes[j+1].puntos` y, claro, te das cuenta que si `j=2`, entonces `j+1=3` es decir, estarías accediendo a una posición que no pertenece al array... mal vamos.

Ese algoritmo de ordenación no está bien implementado. Tienes que usar los dos índices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < 3; j++) {
    if (oyentes[i].puntos < oyentes[j].puntos) {
      aux = oyentes[i].puntos;
      oyentes[i].puntos = oyentes[j].puntos;
      oyentes[j].puntos = aux;

      k = oyentes[i].cedula;
      oyentes[i].cedula = oyentes[j].cedula;
      oyentes[j].cedula = k;
    }
  }
}
```

Aunque, ya puestos, y quizás no lo sepas, las estructuras se pueden copiar con el operador de asignación, con lo que el código final es todavía más legible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < 3; j++) {
    if (oyentes[i].puntos < oyentes[j].puntos) {
      OYENTE aux = oyentes[i];
      oyentes[i] = oyentes[j];
      oyentes[j] = aux;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por todas tus recomendaciones